# I want to print a text file in columns

Tags: command-line, printing, io, text-files

I have a text file which looks something like this:

jdkjf
kjsdh
jksfs
lksfj
gkfdj
gdfjg
lkjsd
hsfda
gadfl
dfgad

[very many lines, that is]

but would rather like it to look like

jdkjf  kjsdh 
jksfs  lksfj 
gkfdj  gdfjg 
lkjsd  hsfda 
gadfl  dfgad

[and so on]

so I can print the text file on a smaller number of pages.

Of course, this is not a difficult problem, but I'm wondering if there is some excellent tool out there for solving problems like these.

EDIT: I'm not looking for a way to remove every other newline from a text file, but rather a tool which interprets text as "pictures" and then lays these out on the page nicely (by writing the appropriate whitespace symbols).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this python code.

```
tables=input("Enter number of tables ")
matrix=[]
file=open("test.txt")
for line in file:
 matrix.append(line.replace("\n",""))
 if (len(matrix)==int(tables)):
  print (matrix)
  matrix=[]
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Since you don't name your operating system, I'll simply assume Linux, Mac OS X or some other Unix...)*

Your example looks like it can also be described by the expression *"joining 2 lines together"*.

This can be achieved **in a shell** (with the help of `xargs` and `awk`) -- but only for an input file that is structured like your example (the result always puts 2 words on a line, irrespective of how many words each one contains):

```
 cat file.txt | xargs -n 2 | awk '{ print $1" "$2 }'
```

This can also be achieved **with `awk` alone** (this time it really joins 2 full lines, irrespective of how many words each one contains):

```
 awk '{printf $0 " "; getline; print $0}' file.txt
```

**Or use `sed`** --

```
 sed 'N;s#\n# #' < file.txt
```

Also, **`xargs` could do it:**

```
 xargs -L 2 < file.txt
```

I'm sure other people could come up with dozens of other, quite different methods and commandline combinations...

---

**Caveats:** You'll have to test for files with an odd number of lines explicitly. The last input line may not be processed correctly in case of odd number of lines.